# Is flash on Chrome the same as Firefox?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, firefox, crash

I have Chrome running a flash game and Firefox running another Flash application. When Flash on Firefox crashes does it affect current Flash running on Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; different instances of Flash run in different processes.

Comment: Thanks minitech! I don't know whether Flash instances on Firefox are linked but on Chrome with multiple tabs running multiple Flash apps, when one crashes the others also crash.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Chrome use PepperFlash by default, which is sandboxed between Chrome process.  I don't believe one should affect the other.

http://blog.chromium.org/2012/08/the-road-to-safer-more-stable-and.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, by default, it is not the same thing, but Chrome is, in general, capable of using the same plugin that Firefox uses. One could symlink the Firefox plugin directory to Chrom's plugin directory and have the exact same binary to do both things.

I came across instances, where the second was preferable for people using both browsers and being frustrated about some peculiarity of Pepper plugin, but this is rather an exception to the rule.